# how do I sort this ajax php script

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery

I have this script

say `index.html`

```
 <html>
    <head>
      <title>Ajax with jQuery Example</title>
      <script type="text/JavaScript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
      setInterval(function(){
        $("#quote p").load("script.php");
      }, 10000);
    });</script>
    <style type="text/css">
        #wrapper {
          width: 240px;
          height: 80px;
          margin: auto;
          padding: 10px;
          margin-top: 10px;
          border: 1px solid black;
          text-align: center;
        }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="quote"><p> </p></div>

      </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

script.php

```
<?php

echo "Hello how are you";?>
```

when loading index.html it is blank for 10 seconds and then it start functioning..how do I get rid of blank and how it can show instantly when browser loads??

Comment: You do realise you're setting an interval of 10 seconds, hence why you see nothing for 10 seconds??

Answer (score 4):

Your `setInterval()` call works as designed: It says *"in 10 seconds and then every seconds, do this...."*

Add a separate "load" call to do the initial filling:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#quote p").load("script.php");  // <--- Add this

  setInterval(function(){
  ....
```